# How to control start and stop video streaming from ESP32-CAM?

Tags: video-streaming, esp32

I'm using ther ESP32-Cam and have started to play around with the [ESP32-CAM Example 2 : Live Video Streaming Server](https://lastminuteengineers.com/getting-started-with-esp32-cam/#esp32cam-example-2-live-video-streaming-server) application which works great.

I'm interested in starting and stopping the stream not by command from the client (via Start Stream/Stop Stream button in browser) but I want to control the Start/Stop option from the ESP32 directly.

I could just call `WiFi.disconnect(false, false);` to stop the stream but it's not great (if there was other data transmission going on as well) and a call to `WiFi.reconnect();` won't automatically resume the stream either. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Append the following code to the end of *app_httpd.cpp*:

```cpp
void stopCameraServer(){
  if (camera_httpd != NULL) {
    httpd_stop(camera_httpd);
  }

  if (stream_httpd != NULL) {
    httpd_stop(stream_httpd);
  }
}
```

And add this at the top of *CameraWebServer.ino*:

```cpp
void stopCameraServer();
```

Then you could stop the HTTP server by calling `stopCameraServer()`